# Activecollab Self Hosted account API Authentication invalid response

Tags: php, api, authentication, activecollab

I am using this API integration https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk

I using this below code to get token:

```
$authenticator = new \ActiveCollab\SDK\Authenticator\SelfHosted('<COMPANY NAME>', 'My Application', '<EMAIL>', '<PASSWORD>', 'http://criticalproject.com.mx/projects');
        $token = $authenticator->issueToken();
        // Did we get what we asked for?
        if ($token instanceof \ActiveCollab\SDK\TokenInterface) {
            print $token->getUrl() . "\n";
            print $token->getToken() . "\n";
        } else {
            print "Invalid response\n";
            die();
        }
```

But I am getting

> "invalid response".

Please check attachment for the error screenshot and suggest me

Below is the screen shot.

[image]

Note: i used dummy company name , application name. But email and password were correct. will that be an issue ?
If it is then how can i get the company name and application name, please suggest

Comment: When I try to access your system with the URL that's in the request, it does not load at all. Prior to making an API connection, make sure that your system is fully functional.

Comment: Please mention which url you are mentioning about, if it is laravel.test/projects/1/edit > then it is my local server (localhost) , i am developing and testing in my localhost

Comment: I work only with data that you provided. URL that I tried is the one that you provided as constructor argument in the example above.

Comment: Yes this my self hosted active collob http://www.criticalproject.com.mx/projects and it is loading fine

Comment: Please pull v3.1.4 of the package (`composer update activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk`). It has improved error communication. In case of request error, you'll get exact API URL that was tried, response code and content type.

Comment: Issue is I wrongly gave the api URL has criticalproject.com.mx/projects but correct api URL is criticalproject.com.mx that is without 'projects' in api URL. Issue is solved now and api is working fine. Thank you very much for checking the issue for me